# How to get a function's result type's SourceLocation in the clang AST

Tags: clang

I've been trying to use libtooling to rename classes in source, and have hit a snag wrt function returns: there doesn't seem to be an API to get the source extent of just the return type.

I could hack it by assuming the return type is before the function id, but this doesn't handle trailing return types in C++11. 
Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Thanks!

```
// simplified example replacing only value type returns
virtual void run(const ast_matchers::MatchFinder::MatchResult& Result) {
    SourceManager& src = *result_.SourceManager;
    const FunctionDecl* const function =
        result_.Nodes.getDeclAs<FunctionDecl>("function");

    CharSourceRange range = Lexer::makeFileCharRange(
        CharSourceRange::getTokenRange(function->getLocStart(), 
        function->getLocation.getLocWithOffset(-1)),
        src, LangOptions());
    _replace->insert(Replacement(src, range, "newClass));
}
```

Comment: functionDecl has [getReturnType()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html#a2935d37297596c57aa383de101a55030) and [getReturnTypeSourceRange()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html#a1ac2b87b937cc44d8980a898851c0c75) as member functions.